# Exception while iterating in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have class `Product` which has field `List<ProductCategoryDetail>` and `ProductCategoryDetail` has a field of `Category` type and `Category` has a field `List<SubCategory>`.

```
Product
  |
  |-----
       List<ProductCategoryDetail>
                 |
                 |----Category
                         |
                         |---------List<SubCategory>
```

My objective is to iterate over list of `ProductCategoryDetail` object for a `Product`.

I am using following code in JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${product.productCategoryDetails}" var="productCategoryDetails" varStatus="status">
    <tr id="category_row">
        <td>
            <form:label path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category">Category</form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:select cssStyle="width:134px" path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category.id" cssClass="category">
                <form:options items="${categories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:label path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].subcategory">SubCategory</form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:select cssStyle="width:134px" path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].subcategory.id" cssClass="subcategory">
                <form:options items="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category.subCategories" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Categories drop down is working fine but subcategories drop down is not getting created and it is throwing following exception:

> 16:19:17,342 ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-10 form.OptionsTag:82 - Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items

Comment: I am putting categories(list of Category Object) in ModelandView and that is why i am not getting any exception there. I am getting exception here,  <form:options items="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category.subCategories" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>

Comment: Did you try to print `productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category.subCategories` and see ?